# Read URL in URLLIB starting from a different starting character

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I open a URL through python and print the characters, but the first approximately 1000 characters are useless and i dont want them to appear. How to I start the print from a number to another predefined number?

I have tried to look up solutions but nothing says anything about starting from a different pre defined number.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

link = "https://www.abc.net.au/" 

#dummy URL. Its on the internet, but dont want to use the real one for privacy

f = urlopen(link)
print(f.readline(1000:2000))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply index the string returned:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen

link = "https://www.abc.net.au/"

f = urlopen(link)
print(f.read()[1000:2000])
```